# how to send the result of svelte-preprocess into a file

Tags: typescript, svelte

Is it possible (and, if yes, how) to save the result of a `svelte-preprocess` run into an external file?

My motivation: I've written a Svelte component using TypeScript - but pointing the `svelte` field of my `package.json` to the original (i.e. TypeScript) source lets non-TypeScript-savvy environments (such as the Svelte REPL) fail with syntax errors.

Thus, what I need is to publish the transpiled version of my original component - without any bundling (allowing Svelte to optimize its final bundle)

[Edit] the accepted answer shown below motivated me to write a Svelte preprocessor which actually solves the mentioned problem. Should anybody else ever be in a similar situation: just have a look at [save-to-file](https://github.com/rozek/save-to-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a preprocessor by yourself and do what you want with the generated code

Make sure to include your preprocessor after `sveltePreprocess` to get the compiled code

```js
plugins: [
    svelte({
      preprocess: [
        sveltePreprocess({sourceMap: !production}),
        {
          script: ({attributes, content, filename, markup}) => {
            console.log({content, filename});
          },
          markup: ({content, filename}) => {
            console.log({content, filename});
          },
          style: ({attributes, content, filename, markup}) => {
            console.log({content, filename});
          }
        }
      ],
    }),
```

You can create a sort of map, and assemble the compiled component since you have the script, markup and style